# Configuração do Tomcat 7 no Eclipse resulta em HTTP Status 404

Tags: java, eclipse, java-ee, tomcat

Baixei a versão *tar-gz* do TomCat 7 e no linux manualmente setei a variável `CATALINA_HOME` digitei o comando `$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh` e acessei `http://localhost:8080/`, funcionou normalmente (*apareceu a home do TomCat*), porem fui tentar adicionar o servidor no eclipse, fiz os procedimentos normais, fui na aba *servers* fui em adicionar um novo servidor, selecionei apache TomCat 7 e coloquei o diretório do TomCat na minha maquina (o mesmo usado na variável `CATALINA_HOME`), dou um start no TomCat e aparece no *log* do eclipse:

> INFORMAÇÕES: Server startup in 562 ms

Mas quando acesso o *localhost* na porta 8080, nada acontece , apenas aparece `HTTP Status 404`, sinceramente não sei o que está acontecendo, alguém teve o mesmo problema? tem alguma ideia?

> versão do tomcat : Apache Tomcat7.0.57
>
> versão do eclipse : Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
>
> Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)
>
> Distribuição Linux: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isto é um comportamento comum da configuração do Apache Tomcat no Eclipse. Isto ocorre porque, quando é criado o server dentro do Eclipse são utilizados os metadados (informações temporárias dentro da pasta Servers) do Workspace do Eclipse, e não o diretório de instalação do Tomcat.

Se preferir, é possível alterar clicando duas vezes no servidor do Tomcat dentro da aba `Servers`, e na opção `Server Locations`, marcar *Use Tomcat installation*.

A diferença é que marcando esta opção, as alterações serão refletidas diretamente do diretório onde o Tomcat está instalado.

Comment: Ola Felipe Soares, obrigado pela resposta, mas por algum motivo as opções do Server Locations não estão habilitadas pra eu modificar, mas de qualquer maneira agora eu sei qual é o problema, Obrigado.

Comment: Eu utilizo o Eclipse no Linux com o Debian e as opções aparecem normalmente (verifique se está executando o Eclipse como administrador da máquina). Aconselho a utilizar o próprio metadado do Eclipse, visto que é mais simples adicionar ou remover uma aplicação no Tomcat.

Comment: Exclui e adicionei dinovo o tomcat, agora consegui mudar, está funcionando, Obrigado.